# HTML import angular2 app and pass parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, polymer, web-component

I want to use webcomponents and HTML import to import an angular2 module into another webapplication which do not use angular2. I know HTML import is only natively supported in few browsers but i will use the polymer framework to pollify other browsers.

I can import the angular app but i'm unable to pass parameters to the angular app from my web app that imports the angular app. I'm trying this:

```html
<dom-module id="sale-stats">
  <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
  <template>
    <!-- contains my angular app bundled js files -->
    <link rel="import" href="imports.html">
    {{saleid}} <!-- this displays the saleid just to see that the parameter is passed to the webcomponent -->

    <app-root saleid='{{saleid}}'>Loading... </app-root>
  </template>

  <script>
    HTMLImports.whenReady(function () {

      Polymer({
        is: 'sale-stats',

        properties: {
          saleid: {
                type: String,
                value: '0'
            }
        },
      });
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<script src="/Scripts/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="http://localhost:9600/salestats/index.html" />
<sale-stats saleid="1234567"></sale-stats>
```

How do i pass parameters to my angular app when using the angular app as a webcomponent that is imported into another app? Or is it just completely wrong to try and import an angular app as an webcomponent?

Comment: you should use webcomponents.js or just htmlimports.js instead of Polymer to do that.

Comment: I am using webcomponents.js in the app that is importing my angular app. Just added the script in code. But i need Polymer in my angular app to support browsers that doesn't support webcomponents natively.

Comment: Webcomponents.js *is* the polyfill that Polymer uses to support various browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to polyfill HTML Imports, you just have to include `HTMLImports.js` which is available in the webcomponents.js repository. You can install it with *bower* (or *npm*):

```
bower install webcomponentsjs
```

Just include the polyfill before the `<link>` element:

```
<script src=".../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/HTMLImports.js"></script>
```

To wait for the imported file to be loaded, you can use the Promise, or instead wait for the *standard* `onload` event. For example:

```
<script src=".../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/HTMLImports.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="imports.html" onload="run( 1234567 )">
```

*Inside the imported HTML file:*

```
<!-- contains my angular app bundled js files -->
<script>
    function run ( id ) 
    {
        var app = document.createElement( 'app-root' )
        app.setAttribute( 'saleid', id )
        document.body.appendChild( app )                
    }
</script>
```

*Notes:* you can also place the `onload` callback function in the main document. Also, the import is synchronous on native implementation (Chrome and Opera); use `async` in `<link>` if you don't want to block the parsing.

Comment: Eventhough this didn't solve my direct problem (i wanted to import as webcomponent into shadow dom) i will give you the answer because you helped me clarify that i could just use webcomponents.js and you made me aware of the onload callback which led me to the solution :)